# Shortcuts to applications failing

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10

I run Ubuntu 17.10 + Unity 7 and things like <kbd>Super</kbd> work and <kbd>Alt</kbd> work; but, any keyboard shortcut to applications like <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> don't work. I have checked my shortcut list and they are all enabled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did u tried to restart the system ? Sometime u need to restart the system to fix some bugs

Comment: Yeah i tried that

Comment: maybe u need to restarting lightdm.

Comment: I'm using GDM and I have already tried restarting services like that.